# Can't mount volume in Docker CLI

Tags: docker

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3
VOLUME /code
```

I execute it using the following command line:

```
docker run -it 626058fb269a --mount src="$(pwd)",target=/code,type=bind /bin/bash
```

However I'm getting this error:

```
[FATAL tini (8)] exec --mount failed: No such file or directory
```

Clearly I'm missing something. If run docker run -it 626058fb269a /bin/bash, the directory is there, but obviously has nothing mounted. I just want to have access to my code from the container. How can I mount this correctly?

Comment: `docker run -it --mount src="$(pwd)",target=/code,type=bind 626058fb269a /bin/bash` works fine on my machine.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it was my ordering of arguments that got me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`docker run` interprets everything after the image name as the "command" part of the command line (passed as command-line arguments to the entrypoint, if present, or else run directly), so your command is

```sh
docker run \
  -it \                    # Container launch options
  626058fb269a \           # Image name
  \                        # Command and its arguments follow
  --mount src="$(pwd)",target=/code,type=bind /bin/bash
```

You don't need to declare a VOLUME in a Dockerfile to mount a named volume or host directory into a container, so for your use the custom image isn't adding anything for you.  I'd probably suggest something like

```sh
docker run \
  --rm -it \               # Container launch options
  --mount src="$(pwd)",target=/code,type=bind \
  continuumio/anaconda3 \  # Image name
  /bin/bash                # Command and its arguments
```

(Better still, develop and test the application locally without Docker, then COPY it in a Dockerfile, so that you can run the image without also being forced to separately copy around the application code.)